# When Hovering Image on the Left, The image on the right change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day! I'm having a problem on how can I start with this. I want the banner style of this site http://www.saksoff5th.com/. I've checked their source code but I don't know how do they do that. They have image on the left and when I hover them, the right image(banner) is changing.

Do you have any idea? CSS of Jquery? I don't know where to start.

Comment: use js change right side display status.

Comment: I just see some codes of jquery or css but its all about Hovering particular image only. Example I hover the facebook icon, it only hover the image only. My problem is, how can I make something like this http://www.saksoff5th.com/ When I hover the left image, the main banner change. :D Thanks @belwood

Comment: Sir @Fancyoung How can I do that? You have any link for tutorials? :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use js or jq for this.

suppose you have two divs of id left and right respectively.

use this code. When you hover left the right on changes accordingly.
Customize this code according to your need.

I am doing it with jq

```
$('#left').mouseover(
 function()
 {
    $('#right').$("p").css({
        "color": "white",
        "background-color": "#98bf21",
        "font-family": "Arial",
        "font-size": "20px",
        "padding": "5px"
    });
 });
```

Comment: Sir, Nothing happens when I integrate you code in my codes. :(

Comment: You need to include jquery file to your code and you are using wrong selectors. First You study about selectors and basics of jquery.  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: Sir Rahul, I know some basic of selectors. What I'm trying to do is how can I make a if else condition whenever I hover the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th images on the left. :) Thanks in advance sir!

Comment: firstly have you tried my code. Take a sample run. play with code just check its working according to you or not.

Comment: Sir @Rahul, Yes I did try your codes but it doesn't respond :(